# Having some type of cron issue which is giving loads of the same report

Tags: cron, model, enterprise-1.14

It's very generic and I'm not really sure how to go about debugging this one. I probably get about 50 reports per day and it's all the same thing.

```
a:3:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:1210:"#0 /var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(848): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/app/Mage.php(353): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore(NULL)
#2 /var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(281): Mage::getStoreConfig('system/cron/sch...')
#3 /var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#4 /var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#7 /var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#8 {main}";s:11:"script_name";s:58:"/var/www/new/releases/20170801161140/index.php";}
```

Usually if i saw anything that was a third party module or in the community or local folder I would look at that to be the suspected issue.

*******updated*********

```
root@vm-prod-web1:/var/www/new/current/var/report# cat 1085673477531 
a:3:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:1526:"#0 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(848): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/Mage.php(353): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore(NULL)
#2 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Helper/Data.php(281): Mage::getStoreConfig('system/cron/err...')
#3 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(260): Aoe_Scheduler_Helper_Data->sendErrorMail(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule), 'exception 'Mage...')
#4 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(605): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#5 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#6 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#9 /var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#10 {main}";s:11:"script_name";s:58:"/var/www/new/releases/20170801205835/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mage::getStoreConfig('system/cron/sch...')` return null value for crontab. 
That means one of your module run in crontab but `storeid` is not passing as null.

How to find the module?

Install AOE_scheduler. check log which module load that time. check in Magento admin setting or `modulename/etc/config.xml` file store_id is passed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the last part. I do have AOE_Scheduler already installed. Check which log?

Comment: I update and now it's saying AOE_Scheduler is the problem.

Comment: In your Magento lot of cron will run. It is not easy job to findout particular module. Aoe scheduler will help you to find easly particular module. Example  error log time  match with AOE scheduler cron job running time. check that particular module.

The problem is storeid missing in one module. The problem is not in AOE :).

Comment: Try restarting Cron.